# Checking availability of an Azure AKS remote cluster

Tags: c#, azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I got a C# Azure function app which deploys services to one of several remote AKS clusters hosted in Azure cloud depending on a user's choice.

I want to have a check to see if the cluster is available before even starting the entire process of trying to deploy a service. Is there some API call or something I can invoke to check if the cluster is available and alive?

Comment: kubectl cluster-info

Comment: @CSharpRocks i need it programmatically within the context of either an Azure function app or an Azure custom task.

Comment: Managed Clusters - Get https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managed-clusters/get?source=recommendations&tabs=HTTP

Comment: There must be a way to get the cluster's status using the Kubernetes Configuration management client library for .NET https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.ResourceManager.KubernetesConfiguration/1.1.0/index.html

Comment: depends on how you define available and alive. In my mind `kubectl get pods -A` would suffice, so do that before starting to do anything

Comment: I don't know how to switch the context programmatically to the remote cluster. That's why I was searching for some REST api

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some API call or something I can invoke to check if the cluster is available and alive

This endpoint can be used programatically to fetch the cluster status.

```
GET /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/{clusterName}?api-version=2021-11-01
```

`properties.provisioningState` from json object can show the current state

Comment: provisioning state only shows if the cluster's infrastructure has finished deploying. It doesn't show you the current health state of of the cluster